# input value + plus button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have input text with value of 0 and two buttons plus and minus.
the weird stuff is when click the button, the increment is by 2 instead of 1...?
2 - 4 - 6...... what is wrong with the script?

```
$(function() {
   $(".PLUS").click(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   var quantity = parseInt($this.siblings(".InputText").val()) +1;
   $(this).siblings(".InputText").val(quantity);
   });
});
```

Comment: Seems to work OK for me..Here is an optimized version (http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/y3pfs/)

Comment: Me too.... http://jsfiddle.net/XcdbL/

Comment: Works for me.  make sure you don't have the onclick code duplicated.

Comment: There's also HTML5... `<input type="number" min="0" step="1" value="6" />`

Comment: Thanks guys for thinking with me!! Dutchie your script works also !!! thank all!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your script is being called twice.
Try this

```
$(function() {
            $(".PLUS").unbind("click");
            $(".PLUS").click(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var quantity = parseInt($this.siblings(".InputText").val()) +1;
            $(this).siblings(".InputText").val(quantity);
            });
        });
```

If it is not the problem, you can also try to change parseInt() for Number().

Comment: Yes now I see that the script has been called twice!!! Thank you Bruno for the input!